# If $|G|=21$, show that at least one of the Sylow $p$ subgroups is normal.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have done something but I am not sure if it's correct.

So $|G|=21$, $21=7\cdot3$

$p=7 \rightarrow n_7=\{\text{factors of }3\}=\{1,3\}\equiv 1 \mod 7$

$3$ isn't congruent $1\pmod 7$.

$1$ is congruent $1 \pmod 7$.

If $n_7=1$ then the Sylow $7$ subgroup is normal.

$p=3 \rightarrow n_3=\{\text{factors of }7\}=\{1,7\}$ congruent $1 \pmod 3$.

$7$ is congruent $1 \pmod 3$.

$1$ is congruent $1 \pmod 3$ but $n_7=1$ would make the Sylow $p$-subgroup normal.

So there is a Sylow $7$ subgroup that's normal and a Sylow $3$ subgroup that is normal.

Comment: Your argument is fine.  You only needed one subgroup, though.